# What is SourceArn when create lambda function through cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a lambda function through cloudformation template, I have ConfigurationLambdaRole, ConfigurationLambdaFunction and ConfigurationLambdaInvokePermission, in ConfigurationLambdaInvokePermission section, what should be the SourceArn? And is there any incorrect thing with my template?

```
Resources:
  ConfigurationLambdaRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'configuration-lambda'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
                - s3.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess

  ConfigurationLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: 'configuration service with lambda'
      FunctionName: 'configuration-lambda1'
      Handler: lambda.handler.EventHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: Java 11
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 120
      Code:
        S3Bucket: configurationlambda
        S3Key: lambda-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      Role: !GetAtt ConfiguratioLambdaRole.Arn

  ConfigurationLambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ConfigurationLambdaFunction
          - Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: 'arn of jar file in s3(configurationlambda)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SourceArn` is an arn of a resource which is going to invoke your function. For example, if your lambda would be invoked through S3 Events Notifications, the `SourceArn` would be the ARN of your bucket.

In your case I don't see why would you need  `AWS::Lambda::Permission`. So I would just remove the entire resource.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code, I want upload my jar file to s3, and upload to lambda through s3, so the code should looks like this, is that correct?

Comment: @WCY You need ARN of bucket, not the jar file. Also you haven't defined any S3 events in your code, so it will not work anyway. In addition, your lambda role is missing s3 permissions.

Comment: can you show me where to put  S3 events in code? I thought what I defined in ConfigurationLambdaFunction section is s3 event, it contains s3 bucket and key

Comment: @WCY You [define](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-notification) it with your bucket. But this would be better for new question, as it diverges a lot from your issue posted of "What is SourceArn " .